# Need to get jenkins build number

Tags: jenkins, expect

In my Jenkins job configure section I am calling an expect script to run.I need to get the current build number value in a variable in the expect script. is it possible to get the build number in a variable?
example. in my Jenkins job i am calling an expect script sample_text.exp in which i need to get current build number in a variable Build_no
is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

yes, it is possible. There is environment variable BUILD_NUMBER. What you mean by "Jenkins job configure section"? In "Execute Windows batch command" in (build section) you can do:

`echo %BUILD_NUMBER%`

to get this number in a different variable:

`set "BUILD_NO=%BUILD_NUMBER%"
echo %BUILD_NO%`

Comment: in my job's configure i am calling an expect script for example filetest.exp...is it possible to use the build number in the expect script without passing it(build number)as an argument

Comment: I don't think so. Why you can not just pass arguments?

Answer (score 3):

Very much possible. You can use the environment variable, BUILD_NUMBER for that in execute shell section. To get a list of all the environment variables that one can use, go to

```
<your_jenkins_url>/env-vars.html
```

For example:

```
http://my-jenkins-box:8080/env-vars.html
```

Logic that I spoke off in my below comment

```
if [ -z ${JOB_URL} ]; then
   echo "*************************** This is not a Jenkins build ***********"
   # Do your stuff here :)
else
   echo "**************************** This is a jenkins build so maven project is built before this script is executed via Jenkins ***************************"
fi
```

Also, remember that if you are running your script with sudo, these environment variables will not be available then

Comment: in my job's configure i am calling an expect script for example filetest.exp...is it possible to use the build number in the expect script without passing it(build number)as an argument

Comment: In your script, reference the variable $BUILD_NUMBER directly. There is one thing you'll have to take care of though. If you run this on your local machine, the script may fail so add a logic like below to make sure that you do jenkins related stuff on jenkins box itself.